# Funky OpenGL cubes

Tags: c++, opengl, blending, cubes

Aha! It seems my problem was that my zNear value given to gluPerspective had to be greater than 0, and I had to enable the depth buffer to get it working. Ive updated the code below to be working.

I've tried to do this a lot, and always thought I was defining my quad vertices in the wrong order, but now, I know its something else.

I've tried enabling Culling, changing frontFace to clockwise, disabling Blending, adding normals, but I always get a cube that looks like this;

[image: what the cube looks like]

Hopefully, you won't even have to look at my code to know what the problem is, as it wasn't too hard to get it like this.

If you don't immediately know what the problem is, here's the code used to set up and draw the cube.

```
// FIXED CODE.
// reshape, called on init, and window resize
void reshape(int w, int h) {
     scrw=w;
     scrh=h;
     glClearColor(0.8,0.8,0.8,1.0);
     glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
     glLoadIdentity();
     gluPerspective(cfov,(float) scrw/ (float) scrh,1,1000); // this is also a part of the fix.
     glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
     glLoadIdentity();
     glEnable(GL_BLEND);
     glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // this is a part of the fix
     glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
     glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
     glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
     glViewport(0,0,scrw,scrh);
}
// drawQuadCube(), called every frame.
void drawQuadCube() {
     glPushMatrix();
     glTranslated(0.5,0.5,0.5);
     glRotated(xangle,0,1,0);
     glRotated(yangle,1,0,0);
     glRotated(zangle,0,0,1);
     glTranslated(-0.5,-0.5,-0.5);
     glBegin(GL_QUADS);
               //   bottom
               glColor4ub(30,30,255,255);
          glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
          glVertex3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
          glVertex3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
          glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
               //   top
               glColor4ub(40,40,255,255);
          glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
          glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
          glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
          glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
               //   left
               glColor4ub(60,60,255,255);
          glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
          glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
          glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
          glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
               //   right
               glColor4ub(60,60,200,255);
          glVertex3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
          glVertex3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
          glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
          glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
               //   near
               glColor4ub(70,70,100,255);
          glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
          glVertex3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
          glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
          glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
               //   far
               glColor4ub(20,20,90,255);
          glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
          glVertex3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
          glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
          glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
          glNormal3f(0,0,0);
          glNormal3f(0,0,1);
          glNormal3f(0,1,0);
          glNormal3f(1,0,0);
          glNormal3f(1,0,1);
          glNormal3f(1,1,0);
          glNormal3f(1,1,1);
          glNormal3f(0,1,1);
     glEnd();
     glPopMatrix();

}
// if that isn't enough, this is the function used to set up the view.
void setView(void) {
     glLoadIdentity();
     gluLookAt(0.5,0.5,-5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0,1,0);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're drawing it inside-out.

Comment: The reason I know it wasn't problem with the vertices is because after getting this problem, I literally copied and pasted the vertex info from a tutorial, and still had the problem. The front-face mode is counter-clockwise.

Comment: Did the tutorial enable backface culling? If not, it probably was inside-out in the tutorial.

Comment: After putting glCullFace(GL_BACK); into the reshape function, nothing changed. [ also with glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE) ]

Comment: How is the depth buffer set up?

Comment: Depth is enabled in glutInitDisplayMode().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your winding mode is incorrect.

glFrontFace defaults to GL_CCW, but your "front-facing quad", in this example the "near" one, is wound clockwise (from the frame of reference of your camera position; note that it's at negative Z, and looking along positive Z).  `glCullFace` defaults to GL_BACK, so it's getting culled.  Set it correctly with:

```
glFrontFace(GL_CW);
```

See also http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glFrontFace.xml

Once you've got that setup, then you'll want to enable depth-buffering, so your quads overpaint correctly without relying on paint ordering.  See: http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/depthbuffer.htm

Comment: Do you mean setting only the front face for the 'near' side to clockwise, or the entire cube? [ adding your code in the reshape function had no visible effect. ] Also, isn't the near face wound counter-clockwise? [bottom-left, bottom-right, top-right, top-left]

Comment: The entire cube should be wound correctly, so that it draws correctly from any angle.  Then to handle overpaint correctly, you'll need to enable depth buffering; otherwise, the cube faces will not overlap correctly (i.e. whatever gets painted last and in the right front-facing direction will be on top).  I've edited the post to point that out.

Comment: I've marked this as the answer not because of the glFrontFace, but it seems my depth buffer was disabled, because of my zNear values.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
```

See http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glCullFace.xml

or:

```
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
```

See http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glEnable.xml

Comment: Using these functions causes some of the quads to disappear completely when viewed at some angles.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what windowing mechanism you were using but incase you are using glut, don't forget to set the GLUT_DEPTH flag while creating the window. Thats a simple common error frequently overlooked.